# How to set the classpath for the set of jars which has the different main class

Tags: java, linux

Can any one suggest me how to set the classpath for the set of jars which has the different main class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question does not have anything that can help us  to answer.. Please provide more information.

Comment: Your question is too vague or too broad, please provide more information like what you are trying to achieve, otherwise, it will get on hold soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
export CLASSPATH=/somePath/jar/firstJar.jar:/someOtherPath/jar/secondJar.jar
```

Without you giving more details, this is the only sensible answer to your question.